# Replace text in cell with comma separated text

Tags: google-sheets

Explanation: 
[image]

I would like to replace the output of column E with the desired output as seen in column F.

Any values that are marked between  should be replaced with the values in column C.

E.g.

Column E row 19 output before change `* 03-007 Fill in 'Change Team' modal with <Team> & <TeamName>`

Text from Column C row 19 to add in values `a new team, thisisnoteam` separated with a comma.

Column E row 19 output after change `* 03-007 Fill in 'Change Team' modal with "a new team" & "thisisnoteam"`

Where `<Team>` is replaced with `"a new team"` and `<TeamName>` is replaced with `"thisisnoteam"`

Comment: Please see link below. Note there are two sheets one called Specs and one called story line with the desired output. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1HpjaVjtIIHGuhT_GXfm8Qw4XMD-zZSF0tASakOXL4yA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this formula in > tools >> script editor and save the project under a name:

```
function TAGS(input,textreplacement) {
  if (input.length > 0) {
    var lst = input.split(",")
    var rep = textreplacement.match(/<[^>]*>/g)
    for (i in lst){
      textreplacement = textreplacement.replace(rep[i],'"'+lst[i]+'"')
    }
    return textreplacement
  }
  else{
    return textreplacement
  }

}
```

Use in the sheet like a sheets formula, example cell `F13 = TAGS(C5,D5)`

[image]

Comment: This formula doesn't add multiple values into multiple fields. 

e.g. row 17 requires both `Team` and `TeamName` to be replaced by `Team A` and `My Team Name`

Comment: This almost works, there are no double quotes around the updated values.

Comment: Just add the quotes around the replacement string. See my edit.

Comment: Thats great is it possible for the desired output to display with the old text if the values cell hasnt been filled in. 

E.g. `* 03-007 Fill in 'Change Team' modal with <Team> & <TeamName>` is displayed until values cell has been added with `Team A,My Team` at which point desired output column will update to display `* 03-007 Fill in 'Change Team' modal with "Team A" & "My Team"`

Comment: Just replace the last line: `return ""` with `return textreplacement`. Edited the iterator. So now it will just replace one value of one value is given, but the string has 2 or more tags.